# Excel VBA function works on cell but not on formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA function but am not able to call it how I want.

I am calling the function in the cell formula editor.

This works: `=myFunction(A2)`

This is what I want, but it does not work: `=myFunction(VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,FALSE))`

The function definition is:

```
Public Function myFunction(Myrange As Range) As String
        'function replaces a regular expression
End Function
```

What can I do to call this on the result of a vlookup formula?

(By the way, is stackoverflow the place for this? Or is this better suited to superuser?)

Comment: This is fine for SO. The problem is that VLOOKUP doesn't return a range.

Comment: `Public Function myFunction(Myrange As String) As String`

Comment: @ScottCraner - might want that to be a `Variant` parameter?

Comment: One can do that, but then in the code one would need to make sure it was not a range before processing to ensure that the code is processing the same type.  I would be explicit in this case, if one is expecting a text string make it a string.  If one is expecting a number make it a double.  Then in the code you know what you should get. @BigBen

Comment: FYI, the new `XLOOKUP` _does_ return a Range